# Did Luke have help from Obi-Wan in using the Force in the wampa cave on Hoth?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, luke-skywalker, the-empire-strikes-back

In *The Empire Strikes Back*, Luke is hanging upside down in the wampa cave and reaches out to pull his lightsaber to him in order to cut himself down. However, we know that at this point his Jedi powers are severely limited, and as we see later in the movie he has much to learn from Yoda. So, as we see him reach out for his lightsaber, it weakly wriggles in place then shoots up to his hand. My question is does he receive any help through the Force from Obi-Wan (who we see a few minutes later) in retrieving his lightsaber from the snow?

Comment: No. Luke using the Force was the trigger for Ben being able to speak to him, not vice versa

Comment: The dupe addresses Luke's mindset and use of the Force. As far as I'm aware, it's not until the new trilogy that we're introduced to the idea that Force spirits can interact with the outside world beyond their deaths.